# How to put multiple figures as rows in the same float in lyx

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, lyx

I want to add multiple figures in one float, and show them vertically , something like as in the following image. can any one help me?

[image]

Image source [frequency tuned salient region detection](http://ivrl.epfl.ch/supplementary_material/RK_CVPR09/)

Comment: You can do that with the `floatrow` package.

Comment: You could also do in in a tabular.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package; each column is a `subfigure` environment; inside each column the three images are placed inside a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.12\linewidth}
  \caption{AC}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} \\
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b} \\
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c} \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.12\linewidth}
  \caption{BC}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} \\
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b} \\
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c} \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.12\linewidth}
  \caption{CC}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} \\
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b} \\
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c} \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.12\linewidth}
  \caption{DC}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} \\
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b} \\
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c} \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.12\linewidth}
  \caption{EC}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} \\
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b} \\
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c} \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.12\linewidth}
  \caption{FC}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} \\
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b} \\
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c} \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.12\linewidth}
  \caption{GC}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} \\
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b} \\
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c} \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Here comes the long description of all 21 images in an array having three rows and seven columns}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]